# Two SSDs in a Macbook Pro with OSX on one and Windows 7 on the other

Tags: windows, dual-boot

Is it possible to have a setup like this?

What I want to be able to have is one SSD with OSX Lion and another SSD with Windows 7 in a usual dual boot setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a conversion kit to fit the second SSD into the optical drive bay there is no reason why this shouldn't work. Personally I equipped my MBP late 2009 with a HD and a SSD (which ran dual boot some time ago) using [Optibay Conversion Kit](http://www.mcetech.com/optibay/), but there might be cheaper ones on eBay.